# php : file exists return false for existing file

Tags: php, file

I am new to the world of PHP.

I am trying a simple program.

1. open a file
2. read the first line
3. line contains another file name
4. Form file path for this filename
5. check if it exists or not.

It always return `file does not exists` but actually the file exists in the computer.

When I ***hardcode the filepath*** in the above step 5,it starts detecting `file exists and evaluates true`.

Below is my code:

```
<?php

$filepath = "/Users/aashok";
$x="myfile";
$file1="$filepath/$x";

function checkFileExists($newFile){
 if(file_exists($newFile)){
        echo "exists";
 }else{
    var_dump($newFile);
 }
}

if(file_exists($file1)){
 $f = fopen($file1, 'r');
 $file2 = fgets($f);
 fclose($f);
 $filepath2="$filepath/$file2";
 // echo "filepath2 : $filepath2 ------ ";
 var_dump($file2);
 var_dump($filepath2);
 checkFileExists($filepath2);
 }else{
  echo "does not exists";
 }
?>
```

The output I get is :
`string(8) "myfile2 " string(22) "/Users/aashok/myfile2 " string(22) "/Users/aashok/myfile2 "`

The directory structure is :

```
aashok$ ls|grep myfile
  myfile
  myfile2
aashok$ pwd
  /Users/aashok
aashok$ cat myfile
  myfile2
```

I am cluesless as what is wrong here.Can someone please help with this.

Comment: `$file2 = fgets($f);` does not set the actual path of the file. *fgets — Gets line from file pointer*

Comment: Also, a recommendation, save files within the project itself, it makes your life much easier since you can call `__DIR__` to get the current path of the php file

Comment: what's the value of `var_dump($file2);`  put it before `checkFileExists($file2);` and check. And please please please don't ->`assume it return /Users/abhinav/newFile2 which is existing`

Comment: @MattSmeets: using mac system.So the filepath is correct

Comment: The return value of `fgets` can include a line-ending, you might need to trim `$file2` before using it

Comment: `file does not exists` was from running `checkFileExists($newFile)`. `$newFile` was `$file2`, `$file2` was from `$file2 = fgets($f);` which maybe not a file name.

Comment: what was displayed from this `echo "filepath2 : $file2 ";`?

Comment: @ildflue : the filepath which i have put in comment  `/Users/abhinav/newFile2`

Comment: Your comments and error messages are not helpful: The message you claim to receive and the output you put under the code does not match what the code can output. Put the **exact** output in your question. Also, use `var_dump()` instead of `echo` to see the exact values of your variables.

Comment: If yo got `/Users/abhinav/newFile2` from `echo "filepath2 : $file2 ";`, then `checkFileExists($file2);` and `checkFileExists("/Users/abhinav/newFile2");` should return the same value, but you said you got different values. right?

Comment: @ildflue : yes I got different values

Comment: And now the question: What's inside `file1`?

Comment: I seriously don't know on what basis this question was downvoted..Why would I ask something if that is working for me

Comment: @jeroen: I have entered the exact code and terminal output as well as replaced`echo` with `var_dump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **file1** contains more than one line, then the call to `fgets` will include the line-ending. When you pass this to `file_exists`, it will return false, since obviously the filename on disk doesn't contain one.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php):

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline **(which is included in the return value)**, or an EOF (whichever comes first).

If you trim the line-endings from `$file2` first, this should work correctly:

Change

```
$file2 = fgets($f);
```

to

```
$file2 = rtrim(fgets($f));
```

Comment: From the new output in your question, it actually looks like you've got a space at the end of the line, but this fix will work for either.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `$file2` is contain just file name, right? it relative path.
Try this code fix your problem:

```
$filepath   = "/Users/abhinav";
$src        = "file1";
$file1      = "$filepath/$src";

function checkFileExists($newFile)
{
    if(file_exists($newFile))
    {
        echo "exists";
    }else{
        echo "file does not exists :$newFile ";
    }
}

if(file_exists($file1))
{
    $f      = fopen($file1, 'r');
    $file2  = trim(fgets($f)); // remove start/end spaces,new line, etc

    //If file is relative with current file, you need this
    $file2  = dirname($file1) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file2;

    fclose($f);
    echo "file1 :$file1 ";
    //assume it return /Users/abhinav/newFile2 which is existing
    echo "filepath2 : $file2 ";
    checkFileExists($file2);//evaluates false in function
    checkFileExists("/Users/abhinav/newFile2");//evaluates true in function
}else
{
   echo "does not exists";
}
```